# confused generating fibonacci sequence

Tags: javascript

**(i)  When I run below code,**

```
var fib = []; 
for(var i=1; i<=10; i++){ 
    if (i === 1) {
      fib[0] = 0;
    } else if (i == 2) {
        fib[1] = 1;
    } else {
        fib[i] = fib[i-2] + fib[i-3];
      console.log(fib[i]);
    }
}

Output: 0 1 undefined 1 NaN NaN
```

**(ii) When I run below code,**

```
function generateFib(num) {
  var fib = []; 
  for(var i=1; i <= num; i++) {
    if (i === 1) {
      fib.push(0);
    } else if (i == 2) {
      fib.push(1);
    } else {
      fib.push(fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 3]);
    }
  }
  return fib;
}
generateFib(10);

Output:  0  1   1   2   3   5
```

I am confused between two code could you please explain me, thank you.

Comment: you never set fib[2]

Comment: Read your code. What happens when `i = 2`?

Comment: Second code does not fail because it pushes new elements to the array. First one fails because it tries to access values in the array that are never there in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the loops iterations one by one

in the third iteration,

`fib[2] = fib[2-2] + fib[2-3];` is `fib[2] = fib[0] + fib[-1];`

`fib[2] = 0 + undefined;`

`fib[2] = undefined;`

in the fourth iteration,

`fib[3] = fib[3-2] + fib[3-3];` is `fib[3] = fib[1] + fib[0];`

`fib[3] = 1 + 0;`

in the fifth iteration,

`fib[4] = fib[4-2] + fib[4-3];` is `fib[4] = fib[2] + fib[1];`

`fib[4] = undefined + 1;`

`fib[4] = NaN;`

You can figure out the rest.

Btw you could use a debugger with breakpoints.

It would be really useful in this situation.

Comment: thank you so much Ali sir now I got my answer step by step, but I never use debugger, how can I use that!

Comment: You are welcome, check firebug from google. Keywords : debugging, browser, breakpoints etc.

Comment: I want to use breakpoints and debugger on my local files, and Firebug does not work on local pages! Do you know any other that work on my local files?

Comment: A little bit of googling :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175883/firebug-in-chrome-doesnt-show-up-on-local-websites